# How can I make this function without classes - Python 3 Tkinter

Tags: python

```
from tkinter import *
class App():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root

    def Function(self):
        self.grid = []
        for i in range(7):
            row = []
            for j in range(6):
                row.append(Button(self.root,width=2,height=1,command=lambda i=i, j=j: self.Click1(i, j)))
                row[-1].grid(row=i,column=j)
            self.grid.append(row)

    def Click1(self, i, j):
        self.grid[i][j]["bg"]="blue"

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
app.Function()
root.mainloop()
```

I need this to function without class. I tried removing the class option but I think that will cause a chain effect for everything else. Please help me remove the classes and just keep methods.

Comment: Why do you need to get rid of the class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can do that but I recommend you don't. But first, a possible solution. This is based on something I started out with: Instead of class you use a main function that runs the loop and has all the methods as subdefs. The external function wrapper is optional but very useful. It clears away all the variables created by the GUI when it exits. Furthermore it allows you to import the script safely and launch it only when you need to.

```
def App():
    root = tk.Tk()
    #app = App(root)

    def Function():
        grid = []
        for i in range(7):
            row = []
            for j in range(6):
                row.append(ttk.Button(root,command=lambda i=i, j=j: Click1(i, j)))
                row[-1].grid(row=i,column=j)
            grid.append(row)

        return grid

    grid = Function()

    def Click1(i, j):
        grid[i][j]["bg"]="blue"

    root.mainloop()

App()
```

Some key points:

- This script doesn't actually work. It's throwing loads of exceptions because of things it doesn't recognise (e.g. "height" and width"). I'm guessing your version is different from mine? Still, it creates a grid of buttons, which is a first step, I suppose.
- All the `selfs` must go since you're no longer using a class
- All the methods, now subdefs, must return the variables they're supposed to create or use global variables, since `self.something` is no longer available.

Now, some advice from someone who initially built their GUI in this very style: **Don't!** For your own sake.

- As it grows it'll become increasingly difficult to manage and expand and, not least, debug and simply read.
- It may not play well with other scripts if you ever plan to import your work from elsewhere.
- When you finally give up and embrace classes, as I did, it will be extraordinarily tedious to translate everything you have created (back) into a class.

Classes are the way to go with tkinter.

Comment: Thank You very much. I'm still a beginner with classes and wanted to see how it would be without them, as a comparison. Anyways, I'll try to implement more of my code with classes, thanks.

Comment: That's understandable. When I started like this my reasoning was that tkinter would be tricky enough without having to learn about classes, too. As it turns out, all you really need to know about classes here is to use `self` and that `self.variable` can be used anywhere the class and persists outside the methods that create them. That last bit is incredibly useful for a tkinter GUI.

P.S. Please consider an upvote or selecting my post as the answer. Thank you.